# VBA Creating Nested Type

Tags: excel, vba

I am studying at excel with vba macro. I am trying to create a type as MessageID. This type has four variable as string such as Message_ID, Message_Name, Message_Byte and Message_Bit. A Message has just one Message_ID, however; a Message_ID has more than one Message_Name and every name has and just one byte and bit. In the other word, I need a Type has some variables. Because of this, I am trying to make the code above work. But these variables need to keep some variables. But, of course, it does not work.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

```
Public Type Message

  Message_ID As String

  Public Type Message_CH

    Message_Name As String
    Message_Byte As String
    Message_Bit As String

  End Type

End Type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to un-nest them, and then use the sub-type as a member of the super-type:

```
Public Type SubMessage
    Message_Name As String
    Message_Byte As String
    Message_Bit As String
End Type

Public Type Message
    Message_ID As String
    Message_CH As SubMessage
End Type
```

You would then access the sub-type from the super-type like this:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim x As Message
    Debug.Print x.Message_CH.Message_Name
End Sub
```

I suspect, though, that you would be better served by writing a class and using that instead.

Comment: Thank you. I am just improving myself in vba and i have just learnt subtype thanks to you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add on Comintern's answer. Order matters. Subtype needs to be defined before the type. If you put the Type text first, and SubType after, you'll get an error message.

Comment: "Invalid Forward Reference" if I recall correctly.